# Is there a way to make Webpack less verbose INSIDE the bundle?

Tags: webpack

Is there a way to make Webpack less verbose ***inside*** the bundle.

I'm evaluating Webpack and Rollup at the moment for a new WordPress theme project, where I wanted to bundle my own JS and third party JS. Rollup is far less verbose.

I couldn't find any config setting, or other question about this.

Example of what I want reduced to the bare minimum or completely removed. There is much more of it in the full bundle. :

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, { enumerable: true, get: getter });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // define __esModule on exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.r = function(exports) {
/******/        if(typeof Symbol !== 'undefined' && Symbol.toStringTag) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: 'Module' });
/******/        }
/******/        Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // create a fake namespace object
/******/    // mode & 1: value is a module id, require it
/******/    // mode & 2: merge all properties of value into the ns
/******/    // mode & 4: return value when already ns object
/******/    // mode & 8|1: behave like require
/******/    __webpack_require__.t = function(value, mode) {
/******/        if(mode & 1) value = __webpack_require__(value);
/******/        if(mode & 8) return value;
/******/        if((mode & 4) && typeof value === 'object' && value && value.__esModule) return value;
/******/        var ns = Object.create(null);
/******/        __webpack_require__.r(ns);
/******/        Object.defineProperty(ns, 'default', { enumerable: true, value: value });
/******/        if(mode & 2 && typeof value != 'string') for(var key in value) __webpack_require__.d(ns, key, function(key) { return value[key]; }.bind(null, key));
/******/        return ns;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = "./builder/assets/toolkit/scripts/javascript/toolkit.js");
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ({

/***/ "./builder/assets/toolkit/scripts/javascript/toolkit.js":
/*!**************************************************************!*\
!*** ./builder/assets/toolkit/scripts/javascript/toolkit.js ***!
\**************************************************************/
/*! no exports provided */
/***/ (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony import */ var uikit__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! uikit */ "./node_modules/uikit/dist/js/uikit.js");
/* harmony import */ var uikit__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(uikit__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__);
/* harmony import */ var uikit_dist_js_uikit_icons__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__(/*! uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons */ "./node_modules/uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons.js");
/* harmony import */ var uikit_dist_js_uikit_icons__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(uikit_dist_js_uikit_icons__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__);
/* harmony import */ var _vendor_canvas_HTML5_Canvas_Exploding_Noodle_Effect_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./vendor/canvas/HTML5-Canvas-Exploding-Noodle-Effect.js */ "./builder/assets/toolkit/scripts/javascript/vendor/canvas/HTML5-Canvas-Exploding-Noodle-Effect.js");
/* harmony import */ var _vendor_canvas_HTML5_Canvas_Exploding_Noodle_Effect_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(_vendor_canvas_HTML5_Canvas_Exploding_Noodle_Effect_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__);
/**
* Toolkit JavaScript
*/
// JQuery is not a dependency of UIkit anymore.
// import jquery from '../../../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery';



// Load UIkit plugins.
uikit__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.use(uikit_dist_js_uikit_icons__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. That is how webpack bootstraps and handles how the modules are loaded.

Comment: So Rollup has a completely different approach to bundling ?
(Because it can do without.)

Comment: Totally. I prefer rollup for libs and webpack for apps

Comment: Sounds like that for me Rollup is the way to go. I was looking for fast, lean, and simple. By opening this question I just wanted to give Webpack a fair chance, and not let my newbie experience with both tools fuel the wrong decision. I'll keep your one-liner (rollup for libs and webpack for apps) in mind because that makes sense. Thanks!